# Count values depending on Equality Compare

Tags: microsoft-excel, comparison, countif

I have a tables that looks like the following:

[image]

I have multiple `Item` rows, and for each there are many `Value` columns, and a single `Result`. What I would like to do in my `TOTAL` is, for each `Value` column, if each `Value X = Result`, then count that.

For example, for `Item 1`, `Value 1 = Result`, so I count that towards that `Value 1` total. Same for `Item 2`, but not `Item 3` because they are different. Same for other `Value` columns. So as you can see, `Value 1` total is 3, `Value 2` total is 2, and `Value 3` total is 4. In my actual worksheet there may be many items and values.

So how do I write a formula for this?

I could write a painful string of multiple `IF` statements like below, but I feel like there should be an easier way:

`=IF(B2=$E2,1,0)+IF(B3=$E3,1,0)+IF(B4=$E4,1,0)+IF(B5=$E5,1,0)+IF(B6=$E6,1,0)`

Is `COUNTIF` the way to go here? Then what is my condition going to be?

`=COUNTIF(B2:B6,???)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use SUMPRODUCT() which will iterate the ranges checking if they match.  And if so the `--` will cause the TRUE to be `1` and the FALSE to be `0`.  It will then sum the resultant array.

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(B$2:B$6=$E$2:$E$6))
```

[image]

Comment: WOW neat, never knew about the `--` notation. Thanks!